# mssql_connect show blank page

Tags: php, iis-7, sql-server-express

i'm new in sql server, i just wanted to connect sql server express edition 2012 with php using iis 7 on windows 7 machine.

here is my code :

```
    $myServer = "ASUS\SQLEXPRESS";
    $myUser = "sa";
    $myPass = "1991";
    $myDB = "test"; 
    
    echo("aaaa");
    //connection to the database
    $dbhandle = mssql_connect($myServer, $myUser, $myPass);
    echo("bbbb");
    
    //select a database to work with
    $selected = mssql_select_db($myDB, $dbhandle)
      or die("Couldn't open database $myDB"); 
    
    //declare the SQL statement that will query the database
    $query = "SELECT *FROM mhs";
    
    //execute the SQL query and return records
    $result = mssql_query($query);
    
    $numRows = mssql_num_rows($result); 
    echo "<h1>" . $numRows . " Row" . ($numRows == 1 ? "" : "s") . " Returned </h1>"; 
    
    //display the results 
    while($row = mssql_fetch_array($result))
    {
      echo "<li>" . $row["nim"] . $row["nama"] . "</li>";
    }
    //close the connection
    mssql_close($dbhandle);
```

my php code running on local iis, i think username, password and servername is correct but when i execution it on local iis, it not show any errors, just 'aaaa' and 'bbbb' not showed.

i think i was wrong in mssql_connect but whats wrong? can anybody help me?

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure, but Newer version of SQL severs doesn't compatible with [mssql](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mssql.php) . You should go with the update [SQLSRV (PHP.NET)](http://php.net/manual/en/book.sqlsrv.php) OR [SQLSRV (Microsoft Site)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296152%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) . I faced same problems with MSSQL and in the end moved to SQLSRV. Now it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

change your code to whats written below so you can catch the error.

```
$dbhandle = mssql_connect($myServer, $myUser, $myPass) or die(mssql_error());
```

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the steps given below to connect MSSQL with php:

1. Settings related to your php.ini file:

   a) search the variable **mssql.secure_connection** in your **php.ini** file and put it to on mode if its off 
   b) remove comment from the dll extention **php_mssql.dll** (i.e. remove the ; from the front of the extention )
2. Settings related to the dll files. Download a file name **ntwdblib.dll** from the internet. you can download it from **[here](http://www.dlldll.com/getdll/4196.html)** or can search on internet for that. copy the downloaded dll to the apache/bin directory and for IIS copy it to the php extention directory (if path not known can be found in php.ini for variable extension_dir) also you need to have your **php_mssql.dll** in your php extension directory. if its not present please download it and copy it to the default php extension directory.
3. **restart all your services** (i.e. php and apache or iis) and you can use the script given below to connect to your SQL Server.

Comment: i can't found php_mssql.dll in my php.ini, so can we add it?